# Qt for Android : QtCreator build/deploy error when executing step "Build Android APK"

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt-creator, fedora

After some web browsing, I still can't figure out why I get the following error when I build a simple basic Qt project for Android in Qt Creator  :

```
10:01:29: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
/home/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ --sysroot=/home/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/ -Wl,-soname,libtestAndroid.so -Wl,-rpath=/home/Qt5.5.1-for-android/5.5/android_armv5/lib -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -o libtestAndroid.so main.o mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.o   -L/home/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi -L/home/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm//usr/lib -L/home/Qt5.5.1-for-android/5.5/android_armv5/lib -lQt5Widgets -L/opt/android/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi -L/opt/android/ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm//usr/lib -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGLESv2 -lgnustl_shared -llog -lz -lm -ldl -lc -lgcc
10:01:29: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
10:01:29: Removing directory /home/qt-android-projects/testandroid/build/android-build
10:01:29: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" INSTALL_ROOT=/home/qt-android-projects/testandroid/build/android-build install
/home/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ --sysroot=/home/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/ -Wl,-soname,libtestAndroid.so -Wl,-rpath=/home/Qt5.5.1-for-android/5.5/android_armv5/lib -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -o libtestAndroid.so main.o mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.o   -L/home/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi -L/home/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm//usr/lib -L/home/Qt5.5.1-for-android/5.5/android_armv5/lib -lQt5Widgets -L/opt/android/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi -L/opt/android/ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm//usr/lib -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGLESv2 -lgnustl_shared -llog -lz -lm -ldl -lc -lgcc
install -m 755 -p libtestAndroid.so /home/qt-android-projects/testandroid/build/android-build/libs/armeabi/libtestAndroid.so
Makefile:1707: recipe for target 'install_target' failed
install: cannot stat 'libtestAndroid.so': No such file or directory
[install_target] Error 1 (ignored)
11:41:30: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
11:41:30: Removing directory /home/qt-android-projects/testandroid/build/android-build
11:41:30: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" INSTALL_ROOT=/home/qt-android-projects/testandroid/build/android-build install
/home/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ --sysroot=/home/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/ -Wl,-soname,libtestAndroid.so -Wl,-rpath=/home/Qt5.5.1-for-android/5.5/android_armv7/lib -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -o libtestAndroid.so main.o mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.o   -L/home/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a -L/home/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm//usr/lib -L/home/Qt5.5.1-for-android/5.5/android_armv7/lib -lQt5Widgets -L/opt/android/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi-v7a -L/opt/android/ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm//usr/lib -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGLESv2 -lgnustl_shared -llog -lz -lm -ldl -lc -lgcc
install -m 755 -p libtestAndroid.so /home/qt-android-projects/testandroid/build/android-build/libs/armeabi-v7a/libtestAndroid.so
Makefile:1707: recipe for target 'install_target' failed
install: cannot stat 'libtestAndroid.so': No such file or directory
make: [install_target] Error 1 (ignored)
11:41:30: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
11:41:30: Starting: "/home/Qt5.5.1-for-android/5.5/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt" --input /home/qt-android-projects/testandroid/build/android-libtestAndroid.so-deployment-settings.json --output /home/qt-android-projects/testandroid/build/android-build --deployment bundled --android-platform android-23 --jdk /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.60-14.b27.fc21.x86_64 --ant /usr/bin/ant
Cannot find application binary /home/qt-android-projects/testandroid/build/libtestAndroid.so.
11:41:30: The process "/home/Qt5.5.1-for-android/5.5/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project testAndroid (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.5.1))
When executing step "Build Android APK"
11:41:30: Elapsed time: 00:04.
```

I don't have spaces in my paths.

Nothing is better when I skip the `make install` step as some related post stated. It just does not show the following lines:

```
Makefile:1707: recipe for target 'install_target' failed
install: cannot stat 'libtestAndroid.so': No such file or directory
```

System configuration:

Under Linux Fedora, as [the Qt's guide](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/androidgs.html) states, I got :

- Android SDK tool (r24.4.1)
- Android NDK (r10e-rc4)
- Apache ant (v. 1.9 in /usr/bin/)
- Java SE Development Kit (java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.60-14.b27.fc21.x86_64)
- Qt5 for Android (v. 5.5.1)

I've installed the Android API 23 SDK tools with the `./android update sdk` command:

[image]

The paths (jdk, sdk, ndk, ant) seem correctly set in QtCreator > Tools > Options > Android.

Thanks

Comment: Is the file `/home/qt-android-projects/testandroid/build/android-build/libs/armeabi-v7a/libtestAndroid.so` present on disk after you get the error?

Comment: What the output says before `[install_target] Error 1 (ignored)`?

Comment: @jpo38: I edited the output in my post.

Comment: Have you downloaded the API-9 "SDK Paltform" from Android's "SDK Manager" tool? Have you tried a more recent API (22 for instance, after downloading it from Android's SDK Manager).

Comment: No because the API-9 is marked obsolete... I'm already using the most recent Android API which is 23... I inserted a screenshot of the Android sdk tools I installed.

Comment: Qt Creator is using API-9 upon compilation, see the log, it references `/home/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/` tool being used.

Comment: OK. I tried both API 9 and 22 and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just re-install the NDK and it works fine now...

Sometimes it's strange...